# SoapUI groovy out put of requestContent contain the param names

Tags: rest, groovy, parameters, output, soapui

I'm using soupUi (pro 5.0) arest request test with custome params rest request
my request:

```
{
     "User": "${#Project#UserName}",
    "ApiPass": "11111",
    "Platform": "${#TestCase#Platfom}"

}
```

*Project.UserName=Sam*

*TestCase.Platfom=Cloud*

I'm using a groovy script to print to a file:

```
file.append(  testRunner.testCase.testSteps["test name"].testRequest.requestContent+'\n' );
```

the output is:

```
{
     "User": "${#Project#UserName}",
    "ApiPass": "11111",
    "Platform": "${#TestCase#Platfom}"

}
```

But i expect to get

```
{
     "User": "Sam",
    "ApiPass": "11111",
    "Platform": "Cloud"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["test name"].testRequest.rawRequestData.toString()
```

See API at: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/RestRequestStepResult.html